# What is the easiest way to plot a window function in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Wat is the easiest way to plot a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) (such as hann, hamming, ...) in LaTeX? With TikZ-pgf?

Comment: The `pgfplots` package (uses TikZ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function from wikipedia, adjusted to degrees, with N=100, and plotted with `pgfplots`

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}



\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot[samples=300,domain=0:99] {
0.5*(1 - cos((360*x)/(99)))};


\end{axis}




\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```